# Can uniqueness of strings (each with an equal number of 1's and 0's) be decided in logspace?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

Let `k` be a positive even integer.

Given a list of `(k choose k/2)` `k`-sequences, each with an equal number of `1`'s and `0`'s, is distinctness decidable in logspace if we're only allowed to read the input once?

In more detail:

Let a sequence have `k` bits.

Let each sequence have an equal number of `1`'s and `0`'s.

There are `(k choose k/2)` such sequences.

Suppose I have a list of sequences.

Suppose there are `(k choose k/2)` sequences in the list.

Can we decide each sequence is distinct from the others in logspace?

If we can read the input multiple times, we can use two logspace counters - and ensure each sequence is not equal to the sequences that follow.

What if we're only allowed to read the input once?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $n={k \choose k/2}$.  Consider the state of the algorithm after reading $n/2$ of the sequences.  How many possible states are there, that it could be in at that point?

Comment: I'd imagine `(k)*(k-1)*(k-2)*...*(k/2+1)*(k/2)` different states. That approaches k^k which is bigger than 2^k. Is that correct?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared, the way to tell whether your answer is correct is to prove it.  You shouldn't need to rely on me to tell you whether it is correct.  Perhaps trying to write out your answer formally and carefully will help you figure out whether you can be confident in it or not.

Comment: To add to D.W.’s hint: if you have to have equal numbers of 1s and 0s, how many distinct strings are there really?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 `k` slots. `2` objects. That's `2^k` combinations. [2^k = (k choose 0) + (k choose 1) +  ... + (k choose i) + ... + (k choose k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) I think. You could look at exponential as combinations of 0 through k. In this case i = k/2. So (k choose k/2) = k!/((k-k/2)!(k/2)!). We can split k!: k! = k*...*(k/2+1)*(k/2)!. Thus the (k/2)! cancel out. Also k-k/2 = k/2. Thus we're left with (k choose k/2) = k*...*(k/2+1)/(k/2)! I don't know how to reduce that further. Nor am I convinced I setup the question right.

Comment: Whatever this answer was, because of the factorial, I assumed it was between 2^k and k^k and thus was beyond log, since log can only do 2^k.